# Pressure sensor for breathing

Tags: sensor, analog, measurement

Could anyone suggest the type of pressure sensor I need to measure human breath? When someone blows into the device I want to measure them blowing in and also sucking out. Could this be done with Barometric sensors?

Comment: Do you really want to measure 'pressure' - like blowing up a balloon, or are you more interested in flow, like blowing out candles?

Comment: @brhans I want to measure the person's breath "blowing" into a tube and sucking air out of the tube.

Comment: Sounds something like the kind of sensor used to assess someone's lung function. Airflow sensor - spirometer.

Comment: So, in your question you say "blowing" which is ambiguous.  We ask "pressure or flow" to clarify, and you say "blowing".  So -- pressure, or flow?  Normal spirometers present very low back-pressure, but that doesn't mean that **you** want to do this measurement with low back-pressure.

Comment: @TimWescott I want to measure flow

Comment: Please edit your question to reflect that.  StackExchange is not like other fora -- it wants a nice self-contained question with nice self-contained answers.

Answer (score 0):

Since a barometric sensor is used to sensing pressure in gases, which is exactly what you want to do: yes. That's the type of sensor you're looking for.